# Looking for Book about Space Travel, stasis, and animals (evolved chickens and cockroaches)

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm going to dump my memories of this book. Hopefully you guys can piece it together. I read this book in 2000/2001

The antagonist of the story, everybody who meets him forgets him soon after (he has sex every night with his secretary but she doesn't remember). He was involved in an accident where stasis protects him from injury. There is a world where only evolved (chickens/roosters that talk and build structures) chickens live. They talk about in the beginning of the book about how the animals evolved. It started with cockroaches traveling with the astronauts and how they mutated. I think the main guy was getting a team ready and one of the team was a precog, each person had a skill or trait that added to completing the task. Any help would be awesome. thanks!!!

Comment: Once again this book sounds like a story I wanna read so I hope it gets identified. I must have got thirty or so books (that I never knew existed) since I joined stack

Comment: I remember really enjoying reading the book but was too young to make a note of it. It was a fun book about life on different planets and space travel.